# REST API : Issues using Aggregate and Iterate Mediator

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

[image]

**Error Message:**
[2013-06-04 11:26:41,039]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:fce9fc4f-a071-4f62-8b5f-e982cf404619, Direction: response, Envelope: **Not in GZIP format**
[2013-06-04 11:26:41,055] ERROR - AggregateMediator Error evaluating expression: /PACKAGE_OFFERS
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Could not find matching elements to aggregate.
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.EIPUtils.enrichEnvelope(EIPUtils.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.getAggregatedMessage(AggregateMediator.java:393)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.completeAggregate(AggregateMediator.java:340)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.mediate(AggregateMediator.java:285)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:265)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:50)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:182)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:443)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:166)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:217)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[2013-06-04 11:27:21,022]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: fe80:0:0:0:b1ac:716:923:abd3%33:61567->fe80:0:0:0:b1ac:716:923:abd3%33:8280

**I have a REST API calling two DataServer Services DS-1 and and DS-2 ,after calling DS-1[XML over REST-GET],I perform an iteration over some repetitive elements and call DS-2[XML over REST-GET].On doing this I get the above listed Error. I am trying to fetch the right element. Please let me know if any additional configurations are required.**

**For Source Code Please Refer this**
 [LINK.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Uf-_NSPiq1d5WsaAB5JZyObD4FmvLoG103UC79eYl_c/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You use receive sequence.So, the 1st endpoint's results(response) will be received in that sequence(ie: iterate seq).After that no receiving sequence. Message flow is broken. You used aggregate in your initial sequence, which doesn't have meaning since, the response from the very first endpoint will be received at iterate-seq.

So, the aggregate will be happen against the initial request, which you sent to your API.

Comment: ## You used aggregate in your initial sequence # I am using the <aggregate> inside the API’s <outSequence> expecting that in the <iterate-seq> the request for first service would be iteratively sent and its response should be captured by < outSequence >.  Do you suggest explicitly setting <send receive="outSequence">. I have taken inspiration from the blog http://dakshithar.blogspot.in/2012/07/routing-and-service-chaining-with-wso2_23.html. The only difference being it uses SOAP and I am doing it on REST. Thanks for your reply..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `<send/>` mediator before closing the `<inSequence>` as mentioned below.

```
            </case>
            <default/>
        </switch>
**<send/>**
    </inSequence>
```

This will make sure that your request will be received by the outSequence.

Answer (score -2):

If you have not decided on any esb … consider UltraESB